# How to merge 1d and 2d tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on passing input to Conv1d layer for which i need to pass time tensor(150) and feature tensor(150,15) as single tensor of [150,150,15] dimension but unable to do so

I tried using stack function of tensorflow

```
inp=tf.stack([features,times],axis=1)
```

I expect to get tensor of `shape[times,features]=[150,150,15]`.
But
I'm getting this error,

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'stack' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [150,15], [150].
```

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) expects tensors with the same rank and shape. In your case, both don't match. Here, rank is basically the number of indices required to index elements of the tensor. Looks like `features` has a rank of 2 and `times` has a rank of 1.
2. What you are trying to achieve isn't logically sound. Think of it this way:
   `times` has 150 elements. `features` has 150*15=2250 elements. How do you expect to get 150*150*15=337500 elements by combining these two tensors which have a total of 150+2250=2400 elements? Unless you plan on duplicating/adding more elements, this is not possible.